# Is it ok to declare an object to be equal to itself in Javascript for the sake of refactoring a large project

Tags: javascript, eclipse, oop, refactoring

I'm working on a very large javascript web app that doesn't really have a method to it. There seems to be an attempt to declare everything as part of a master object called "app".  The original program existed as a single app.js file over 300k lines of code where the following was declared:

```
var app = {};
```

Beyond that everything in the app is written as such.

```
app.somefunction = function(args, callback) { 
    some code
};
```

This apparently allowed for the author to handily use Eclipse IDE "outline", which I confess I have started to enjoy having, never previously having been an IDE user I'm becoming a convert to the niceties they provide.

My question is, as I work on a phased refactor of this huge codebase, potentially trying to merge it into some sort of more established framework perhaps using something like require.js, is it OK to split the "app.js" up into smaller files and for the sake of sanity to be able to use the IDE outline declare app to be equal to itself in each one.

```
app = app;
```

I've tested this, it works from what I can tell and it allows the IDE to add all the subsequent functions to the outline window while making the project a little more manageable while I learn what it is actually doing. Are there any drawbacks to doing this? I imagine some async loading issues might occur; this could possibly add to client side overhead; or is this perfectly acceptable?

I realize that this is sort of a code philosophy question, but the simple Q&A would be, what effect would app=app; have?

Comment: You should not have any trouble splitting files up. I don't see why you need to use `app = app` at all, as it will not really do anything. Anyways this might be a better fit for programmers stack exchange site.

Comment: The trouble was within the IDE, not having a master reference to the var app; in the split up files did not allow Eclipse to "parse" that file.  Additionally there are async issues, the answer by @CupawnTae addresses nicely.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no problem doing that.

In fact, this is pretty common code:

```
var app = app || {};
```

to initialize a variable only if it doesn't already have a value. In the case where it does already have a value, it will be exactly equivalent to your `app = app;`

This technique can also be useful for initializing a large object like you have in multiple chunks, allowing you to reorder and omit chunks at will, while being sure that no chunk is going to wipe another's initializations by doing `var app = {}`

Comment: Thanks for the idea of adding the initializing code as well that could alleviate any async issues as I work through this mess.